# How to model a book in MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, data-modeling

How can I model a book in a MVC. I'm using Ruby on Rails.

A book has chapters, and chapters has pages.

Should I use a book as a model, or should there be seperate model each for book, chapter and then pages.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the books. For example, do you need to work with individual chapters or pages or is it enough to know how many there are?

Comment: Yes, users will be able to browse complete books online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most natural way of doing this is:

book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chapters
end
```

chapter.rb

```
class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  has_many :pages
end
```

page.rb

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chapter
end
```

Then in whatever view you are when you call your book (haml):

```
- for chapter in @book.chapters
  = chapter.title
  - for page in chapter.pages
    = page.content
```

and you can paginate however you see fit.

EDIT
To @apneadiving point, added includes for N+1 queries. So from your books_controller.rb, to reduce the number of queries, you can call:

```
def show
  @book = Book.includes(:chapters => [:pages]).find(params[:id])
end
```

This will load the Book with all of its associated chapters and pages without having to do additional queries.

Comment: you're missing all the necessary includes to prevent N+1 queries

Comment: Will this create a 2 level nested models ?

Comment: Yes. There will be 2 levels of nesting.